# STM32F0, stopping timer at the end of the counting period

Tags: stm32

How to stop the STM32 MCU timer (general-purpose) at the end of the counting period (counter reaches TIMx_ARR value), not immediately e.g. in the middle of period of running counter. This is on stop request that might occur at any time.

Comment: Define "counting period". Is it possible to trigger an interrupt at the end of this "counting period" ?

Comment: Counting period is time for one full timer run (defined by TIMx_ARR register). I rather thought about timer peripheral configuration, if possible. Interrupt might be not precise enough.

Comment: What purpose does the timer serve anyway?  Eg, why do you care if it does or does not keep counting past the end of the current cycle?

Comment: what part of the st documentation did you not understand?

Comment: @ChrisStratton It serves for synchronized operation of DMA channels triggered by timer events. To stop the timer at a specific time (here at the end of the cycle) is important because each timer run gives corresponding DMA triggering sequence that has to be fully completed for every run.

Comment: @old_timer Going through the documentation I couldn't find an explicit solution, that is why I ask.

Comment: What did st say when you asked them?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Timer One-Pulse mode? It can be used to run the timer for a single period. As far as I understand your question this could solve your problem.

Another posssibility would be the break function.
It will set the TIM output module back to reset state based on different sources. Most of them are internal failure detection events but you can also use a comparator input.

Comment: Please be more specific about what *exactly* you mean in the context of the capabilities and controls given in the reference manual of the chip in question.